Lex S-Expressions C++
I'm trying to build a high-performance, S-Expression based, C++/LLVM compiled DSL. I've written a small lexer for it, but I'm getting an infinite loop for all test cases I try without errors (which are caught and handled fine). What could the reason be?
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class TokenType {
    BLOCK,
    IF,
    LET,
    VAR,
    QUOTE,
    SET,
    LAMBDA,
    MACRO,
    INTEGER,
    FLOAT,
    STRING,
    BEGIN,
    END,
    SYMBOL,
    BUILTIN,
    TERMINATE
};

struct Token {
    TokenType type;
    std::string value;
};

class Lexer {
    std::string code;
    unsigned index = 0;

    Token gettok(void) {
        std::string data;

        while (index < code.length() && code[index] != '(' && code[index] != ')' && code[index] != '"' && !std::isspace(code[index]))
            data += code[index++];

        // Handle (...)
        if (data == "(") return { TokenType::BEGIN, data };
        if (data == ")") return { TokenType::END, data };

        // Handle $ID
        if (data[0] == '$') return { TokenType::SYMBOL, data };

        // String/Number/Comment handling are not relevant

        // Handle special operators
        if (data == "block") return { TokenType::BLOCK, data };
        if (data == "if") return { TokenType::IF, data };
        if (data == "let") return { TokenType::LET, data };
        if (data == "var") return { TokenType::VAR, data };
        if (data == "quote") return { TokenType::QUOTE, data };
        if (data == "set") return { TokenType::SET, data };
        if (data == "lambda") return { TokenType::LAMBDA, data };
        if (data == "macro") return { TokenType::MACRO, data };

        // Handle builtins
        return { TokenType::BUILTIN, data };
    }
public:
    Lexer(std::string const& arg) : code(arg + "  ") {}

    std::vector<Token> lex(void) {
        std::vector<Token> out;
        Token next = gettok();

        while (next.type != TokenType::TERMINATE) {
            out.push_back(next);
            std::cout << index << ": " << data << "\n";
            next = gettok();
        }

        return out;
    }
};

auto test= R"(
(function main (x) (block
    (let $out zero)
    $out)))";

int main(void) {
    Lexer lexer(test);
    auto foo = lexer.lex();
    for (auto& bar : foo) std::cout << bar.value << std::endl;
}

I tried modifying the example, I rewrote the whole thing multiple times (this is the most recent version), stepped through the code, and tried asking ChatGPT & Copilot to see if they could catch the error (which they could not).
The result I get is a series of 2: seperated by newlines printing infinitely in a loop.

Please edit your post with a plain-text example of the language you are lexing or parsing.

Where do you declare the variable example? Is it supposed to be test?

Rather than using if statements to convert text to tokens, try using std::map<text, token>.  You could use const structure also.  The structs advantage is that it doesn't need to be constructed at run-time; you can access directly from the data segment.

gettok() never returns TokenType::TERMINATE. So you have an infinite while loop.

You could make each token a class, and add methods like parse and execute.

@ThomasMatthews I provided one as example.

@Barmar Sorry! I was simplifying the identifiers for the post, so I had a typo. I'll fix that.

@ThomasMatthews I was using a std::unordered_map<std::string, Token>, but I found that the slowest part (the strcmp) was happening the same amount of times, so I thought it wasn't worth the verbosity.

@ThomasMatthews I like struct because it's public-implicit, but I do plan on adding methods.

@Barmar Could you please give that as an answer, so I can accept/upvote it?

I think there are other problems. When there's whitespace, you never increment index. So the while loop inside gettok() gets stuck.

You need to learn to use a debugger, but that won't be necessary to work out what happens when your scanner encounters a (. Don't read what you think you wrote, read what you actually wrote and play along with the code.
